# Correct uri for DeleteAgentUser (Google Homegraph)

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to use the DeleteAgentUser of Homegraph to unlink a user with Google. I already implemented the ReportState and the correct uri for this is: `https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:reportStateAndNotification`. So I thought the DeleteAgentUser has to be: `https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:deleteAgentUser` but I'm getting a '404 Not Found' Error.

I tried it with:

```
https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:deleteAgentUser
https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/deleteAgentUser
https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:DeleteAgentUser
https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/DeleteAgentUser
```

everything with post and delete request and always getting the error.

What is the correct Homegraph uri to delete a user from Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the RPC defined in the public protobuf](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/home/graph/v1/homegraph.proto#L90), it seems that the implementation is defined as:

```
rpc DeleteAgentUser(DeleteAgentUserRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    delete: "/v1/{agent_user_id=agentUsers/**}"
  };
}
```

So, it seems like you'd send a `DELETE` request to `https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/{agent_user_id}` or maybe `https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/agentUsers/{agent_user_id}` with your agent user id, and signed with your authorization token similar to Report state.